# setuptools: add entry points from several packages in the same group

Tags: python, plugins, package, setuptools

I want to add several plugins in the same entry points group with setuptools.

package1:

```
setup(                                                                                       
    py_modules=['api', 'internal'],                       
    entry_points={'parsers': ['dummy1 = api:DummyAPI1', ]}
 )
```

package2:

```
setup(                                                                                    
        py_modules=['api', 'internal'],                     
        entry_points={'parsers': ['dummy2 = api:DummyAPI2', ]}
     )
```

After installation of a both plugins I have the only last installed entry point. Is it expected behavior? Can I add several plugins in the same group from different packages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found. I'm a lazy dude - I didn't added a `name` argument to a `setup` function call in both of packages. By default a name is UNKNOWN. Obvious that both of the packages had the same name so for a system these are the same package so `setuptools` overwritten the group.

**Always use `name` argument for `setup` method.**